# arrange by two factors

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-factor

I have been trying the whole day to arrange two factor levels called "type" and "name" by a numeric value called "score", and plot by category type (with color determined by type) ordered by score. I am also trying to get the group called "ALL" on top so it is separated by the other 3 categories in "type". My attempts until now have been very unsuccessful, I don't get why I can't even get the reordering correctly. Any help is very appreciated.

This is my data:

```
df = structure(list(score = c(12, 12.2, 12.5, 12.3, 12.2, 12.4, 12.5, 12.7, 12.1, 12.8, 12.4, 12.3, 12.2, 12.6, 12.8, 12.1, 12.5), range1 = c(0.003356, 1.20497, -0.128138, -42.6093, -41.1975, -44.706, -20, -46.4245, -0.543379, 2.09828, -20, -20, -44.2262, -46.6559, -20, -20, 2.37709), point = c(1.56805, 2.11176, 0.1502, -22.6093, -21.1975, -24.706, -0.491829, -26.4245, 2.49973, 2.94457, 0.0443572, 0.0208999, -24.2262, -26.6559, 2.69408, 3.22951, 3.33255), range2 = c(2.3767, 2.73239, 0.430373, 4.34247, 4.96875, 3.78027, 1.91331, 4.07937, 3.54538, 3.5491, 1.87162, 2.41067, 5.26578, 4.50965, 4.55967, 5.05772, 3.97742), type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("ALL", "A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), name = structure(c(13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 17L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 16L), .Label = c("B_vision1", "C_vision2", "C_vision3", "B_vision4", "B_vision5", "A_vision2", "C_vision4", "B_vision6", "C_vision6", "C_vision5", "C_vision1", "B_vision7", "B_ALL", "C_ALL", "A", "C_vision7", "B_vision3"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("score", "range1", "point", "range2", "type", "name"), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have tried all these options:

```
df$name2 = reorder(df$name, -df$score)
# df$name <- reorder(df$name, -df$score)
df <- transform(df, category2 = factor(paste(name, type)))
df <- transform(df, category2 = reorder(category2, score))

#library(plyr)
#df = arrange(df,type, name)

ggplot(df, aes(x=name, y=point, ymin=range1, ymax=range2, colour=type)) +
    geom_pointrange() +
    coord_flip()
```

or

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=category2, y=point, ymin=range1, ymax=range2, colour=type)) +
    geom_pointrange() +
    coord_flip()
```

I am trying to get something similar to the grouped forest plot on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23182942/how-to-add-cluster-horizontal-lines-in-a-ggplot2-forest-plot) but with each group defined by `names` and reordered by `score`.

Comment: Convert type and name to character columns instead of factors. Other option is to keep them as factors but re-order the levels.

Comment: Thank you, the character conversion alone doesn't solve it though...d$type=as.character(df$type); df$name=as.character(df$name); ggplot(df, aes(x=name, y=point, ymin=range1, ymax=range2, colour=type)) + geom_pointrange() + coord_flip()

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected output?

Comment: Hi Zelazny and thank you for your reply, I am trying to get something similar to a forest plot (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23182942/how-to-add-cluster-horizontal-lines-in-a-ggplot2-forest-plot) but with each group defined by "names" reordered by the "score"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've interpreted what you're trying to do correctly, but I might have got it wrong.

The names (and scores) can be ordered by the sorted list of scores as

```
ordered.names  <- as.character(df$name)[order(df$score)]
ordered.scores <- as.character(df$score)[order(df$score)]
```

Re-ordering the name levels (with the score annotated) is then

```
df$name <- factor(df$name, levels=ordered.names, labels=paste(ordered.names, "(", ordered.scores, ")"))
```

Plotting these with `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot)
ggplot(df, aes(x=name, y=point, ymin=range1, ymax=range2, group=type, color=type)) + 
  geom_pointrange() + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=0))
```

produces

[image: ggplot of point by name, arranged by score, colored by type]

If you want this split up by type as well, you can facet the plot

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=name, y=point, ymin=range1, ymax=range2, group=type, color=type)) + 
  geom_pointrange() + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=0)) + 
  facet_wrap(~type, ncol=4, scale="free_x")
```

[image: ggplot of point by name, arranged by score, colored by type, facet by type]

Comment: Jonathan, thanks so much. Yes it was the color by type I was looking for, and facets for type=="ALL" versus all the others actually, maybe this is too complicated though as I think I would have to create another variable for this, anyway this is definitely extremely helpful for the ordering of factors based on scores, and I can go from here! Thank you very much!